# I can not use Google Fusion Tables API

Tags: api, rest, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to use the Google Fusion Tables API without success.

I created a table, set it to Public and I'm trying to access the API for my browser to this address:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%201pheecBEHLRXeMA1cDSNGqhuXJ7srp9A3i1r3sdd6%20ORDER%20BY%20nome&key=my_key_access
```

But I always get this response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

My table has registered data

What can be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must also enable the **download**-option for the table to be able to request data via the Fusion Tables API